# how to find out Battery consumption of each application in android device

Tags: android, statistics, power-management, consumption

Could any one tell me the way, how to find out the battery usage of each application in android device.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Battery consumption depends on many different factors, for example Wifi usage, GPS usage, CPU usage, etc... all of which can be shared and used at the same time by many different applications. As an indicator you might want to use the CPU usage of applications, which can be seen in the application management page.

Comment: But it is the Android 1.6 verion new feature as per android site(http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-1.6-highlights.html), however I didnt find any APIs for this link, Will it never be possible ?